# What does : mean in C?

Tags: c, struct, qemu, bit-fields

While looking through the source package for QEMU, I found in the exec.c file:

```
struct PhysPageEntry {
    /* How many bits skip to next level (in units of L2_SIZE). 0 for a leaf. */
    uint32_t skip : 6;
     /* index into phys_sections (!skip) or phys_map_nodes (skip) */
    uint32_t ptr : 26;
};
```

I was wondering what the : operator means. I could not find it in a list of syntax definitions for C.

Comment: this is called [bitwise structure](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a structure declared with bit fields and the structure members are called **bit fields**: *A
bit field is set up with a structure declaration that labels each field and determines its width*. The above definition causes `PhysPageEntry` to contain one 6-bit field and one `26` bit field members namely `skip` and `ptr` respectively. Its signature is

```
struct
{
      type [member_name] : width ;
};
```

Here *width* is the number of bits in the bit-field. *The width must be less than or equal to the bit width of the specified type*.

Answer (score 2):

`struct PhysPageEntry` declares two [bit fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) `skip` and `ptr`.  This is basically to allow the struct to pack these odd lengths (in terms of bits) efficiently.  If the author didn't do this, the struct would likely be 8 bytes long (on a 32-bit architecture).

Answer (score 1):

It represents number of bits. It's mostly used for unions:

```
struct byte {
  unsigned a : 1;
  unsigned b : 1;
  unsigned c : 1;
  unsigned d : 1;
  unsigned e : 1;
  unsigned f : 1;
  unsigned g : 1;
  unsigned h : 1;
};
```

You can read [this](http://cplus.about.com/od/learningc/ss/lowlevel_10.htm) too for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Its called a bitfield. Within a structure or union
declaration, this declares 'skip' to be a "bit field" of 6 bits width. They are to be used inside of structures. If it helped please vote as right!